# Get facebook user info

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'd like to know if it is possible to get userid or email for all people with same first name by using FQL and API. I mean all people with first name, like Mary, they don't have be my friends or fans. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. Let us know what you find out!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

**FB user must give you permission to query their account information**. Until then, you can't get any information on them (so of course, you can't query every FB user named *Mary*).

Comment: There are some facebook apps, like social lead freak, can do that but only partially. When I enter keyword like "Mary" it can only give me around 200 entries. How do they do that?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't do that.

As Simon said *FB user must give you permission to query their account information.* An APP can access information for only those users, who have given that permission to the APP.

For example, the apps that you have mentioned in comment, social lead freak etc. will only show the results for those users which have given permission to that particular app. This means that there can be thousands of users on Facebook with the first name "Marry", but out of those thousands of users, only around 200 are using that APP (that is, have given permissions to access their data). Hope that explains the why they are doing that **partially**.

Comment: @user3043276 If you are satisfied with the answer, you can accept it.